환경 vs 분위기, whats the difference?
For 환경, I know that this word can refer to the natural environment. On HTSK, it says it can also mean environment in a metaphorical sense, with the meaning of "atmosphere / mood".
분위기 also means atmosphere / mood, so what is the difference?


그 사람 분위기가 좋다. (some romantic meaning)

그 카페 분위기가 좋다.
->Here, "분위기" can refer to the overall mood or emotional feel of a person or place.

그 사람은 불우한 환경에서 자랐지만 성공했어.

In this context, "환경" refers to the person's background or circumstances,
불우한 환경 implies poverty here.

explain in korean

분위기 雰圍氣 implies 기운(氣).
어떤 사람이나 공간이 "뿜어내는" 느낌입니다.
someone or something gives off 분위기.
환경 環境
어떤 대상을 "둘러싼"(環) 배경/조건/상황에 가깝습니다.
환경 surrounds someone or something.
